# YouTube Data API v3 の再生リストのupdateメソッドの不具合

Tags: youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API v3 の再生リスト(Playlists)のupdateメソッドで再生リストの説明(description)を更新したいのですが、updateが成功したレスポンスが返ってくるのに、実際には更新されない場合があるようです。１回で更新される場合もあれば、２回３回とリトライしてようやく更新できる場合もあります。こちらの環境ですとAPI Explorer で試しても同じ現象を再現できますので、一度同じ不具合が発生するか試して頂けませんでしょうか？また、この問題の原因や対策など分かりましたら教えて下さい。